# Java: Moving JButtons vertically in a JPanel with BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

In my program, I need to have three buttons. I am using a `BoxLayout` in the `JPanel`, and I have managed to move them to the dead center of the screen. They are the correct size and are in the correct horizontal position, but I want to move them up to the top of my frame. What should I use to do this?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Library extends JFrame {

    private JFrame jf1;
    private JPanel jp1;
    private JButton jb1;
    private JButton jb2;
    private JButton jb3;

    public Library() {
        jf1 = new JFrame("Library");
        jf1.setVisible(true);
        jf1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf1.setSize(1080, 900);

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        jf1.setLocation(dim.width/2-jf1.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-jf1.getSize().height/2);

        jp1 = (JPanel) jf1.getContentPane();
        jp1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jp1, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        jb1 = new JButton("Genre");
        jb1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(140, 60));
        jb1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 60));
        jb1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 60));
        jb2 = new JButton("Author");
        jb2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(140, 60));
        jb2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 60));
        jb2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 60));
        jb3 = new JButton("Title");
        jb3.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(140, 60));
        jb3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 60));
        jb3.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 60));

        jp1.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(300, 0)));
        jp1.add(jb1);
        jp1.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20,0)));
        jp1.add(jb2);
        jp1.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20,0)));
        jp1.add(jb3);       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Library shoe = new Library();
    }
}
```

Comment: What about your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701435/java-moving-second-rectangle-using-different-keys-with-keylistener? Don't forget to "accept" answers when you get help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I want to move them up to the top of my frame.

By default the content pane of the frame is a BorderLayout so I would keep this as the layout and then just create a panel for the buttons and add this panel to the top of the frame.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new FlowLayout() );
panel.add(button1)
...
add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and working examples.

> I am using a BoxLayout in the JPanel,

However if you want to do it by using a BoxLayout then you have to tell the BoxLayout how to align each component vertically. The default value for a JButton is to align it in the center of the available space.

If you want it at the top then you need to change each button:

```
jb1.setAlignmentY(0.0f);
```

Also, don't hardcode the "rigid area" at the start of the panel. Instead you want to use `Box.createHorizontalGlue()` at the start and end of the panel. Then the components will adjust as the width of the frame is changed.

Again, the tutorial has a section on `How to Use BoxLayout` that will explain the above.

Answer (score -1):

Use   button_name.setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT); // for all three buttons , Thus your code changes to:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Library extends JFrame {

    private JFrame jf1;
    private JPanel jp1;
    private JButton jb1;
    private JButton jb2;
    private JButton jb3;

    public Library() {
        jf1 = new JFrame("Library");
        jf1.setVisible(true);
        jf1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf1.setSize(1080, 900);

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        jf1.setLocation(dim.width/2-jf1.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-jf1.getSize().height/2);

        jp1 = (JPanel) jf1.getContentPane();
        jp1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jp1, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        jb1 = new JButton("Genre");
        jb1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(140, 60));
        jb1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 60));
        jb1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 60));
        jb1.setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT);
        jb2 = new JButton("Author");
        jb2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(140, 60));
        jb2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 60));
        jb2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 60));
        jb2.setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT);
        jb3 = new JButton("Title");
        jb3.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(140, 60));
        jb3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 60));
        jb3.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 60));
        jb3.setAlignmentY(TOP_ALIGNMENT);

        jp1.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(300, 0)));
        jp1.add(jb1);
        jp1.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20,0)));
        jp1.add(jb2);
        jp1.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20,0)));
        jp1.add(jb3);       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Library shoe = new Library();
    }
```

Comment: (1-) yes, this suggestion was given 20 minutes earlier. No need to repeat the suggestion.